# Exibir qrcode em um alerta

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, qrcode

Tenho este código:

```js
$("#exemplo1").click(function(){
  $('#codigoQrCode').qrcode(JSON.stringify('teste'));

    //se vcs clicarem aqui, aparecerá o qrcode(canvas)
 });
 
 $("#exemplo2").click(function(){
  alert($('#codigoQrCode').qrcode(JSON.stringify('teste')));

    //aqui eu gostaria de exibi-lo no alert, como vcs podem ver ele me retorna o objeto 
 });
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.qrcode/1.0/jquery.qrcode.min.js"></script>

<div id="codigoQrCode"></div>
<button id="exemplo1">Clique 1</button>
<button id="exemplo2">Clique 2</button>
```

Tem alguma maneira de exibir esse qrcode/canvas em um alerta?

Comment: Não acho que seja possível. Até onde eu sei, a função Alert do javascript só aceita texto (string). Talvez a saida para o seu caso seja usar Modal (ou Dialog).
Nesse link: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/ tem o exemplo da Modal usando JqueryUI. E também se vc pesquisar no google vc vai achar varios outros tipos

Comment: Na [documentação da função `alert()` no W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp) você pode observar que esta função espera como parâmetro uma `string`. Caso seja passado um objeto, ele é convertido para `string` também, que é oq te acontece no seu exemplo.

Comment: Vale a pena dar uma olhada nessa lib: [Sweet Alert](https://sweetalert.js.org/). Você pode substituir os alerts do seu projeto por esses modais personalizados. É fácil de instalar, de usar e existem diversos modelos de mensagens. Na realidade o alert está meio que caindo em desuso na visão de UX, seria mais interessante você gastar um tempo tentando migrar para alguma lib ou fazer seus próprios modais.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode simular um alert, utilizei o jquery ui para criar um modal para apresentar o Qr Code, mas você pode também criar uma personalizada de acordo com a sua preferencia, veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
$("#exemplo1").click(function(){
  $('#codigoQrCode').qrcode(JSON.stringify('teste'));
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.qrcode/1.0/jquery.qrcode.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<button id="exemplo1">Clique 1</button>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <div id="codigoQrCode"></div>
</div>
```